# Update each row with each list/dictionary value

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-sheets, gspread

I'm trying to update each row with the elements from the list/dictionary, however, all values are being updated (overwritten) only in the first cell in the range. I would like to add them as a list/table.
Below is my current code and attached is an example image of how I would like the table to be formed.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import gspread
import time
import datetime
import re

driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)
    

while True:

    gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')

    sh = gc.open('Luciana-2022')

    oos = sh.worksheet("OOS")
    
    time.sleep(10)

    walmartLinks = ["https://www.walmart.com/ip/Motioneaze-Motion-Sickness-Relief-Topical-Oil-08-fl-Oz-20-application/12346124", "https://www.walmart.com/ip/Penn-Championship-Extra-Duty-Tennis-Ball-Pack-6-Cans-18-Balls-Pressurized-Suitable-for-Hard-Tennis-Courts/11186275", "https://www.walmart.com/ip/Woolite-Damage-Defense-Liquid-Laundry-Detergent-66-Loads-Regular-and-HE-Washers-100-Fl-Oz-Packaging-may-vary/15610733", "https://www.walmart.com/ip/Mott-s-100-Original-Apple-Juice-8-fl-oz-bottles-6-pack/36874000", "https://www.walmart.com/ip/Butternut-Mountain-Farm-100-Pure-Vermont-Maple-Syrup-32-fl-oz/49058126", "https://www.walmart.com/ip/Queen-Helene-Cocoa-Butter-Hand-Body-Lotion-16-oz/25991731"]
    list = []

    for item in walmartLinks:
        u = driver.get(item)
        time.sleep(5)

        try:
            
            time.sleep(10)
            stock = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="fulfillmentLabel-1P" and contains(., "arrives by")]')))
            stockValue = "In Stock"
        except:
            stockValue = "Out of Stock"
            pass

        try:
            soldby = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="ml2"]')
            soldbyValue = soldby.get_attribute("innerText")

        except:
            soldbyValue = "No seller"
            pass

        try:

            title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//h1[@itemprop="name"]')
            titleValue = title.get_attribute("innerText")
        except:
            titleValue = "Product not found"
            pass
        
        try:
            upc = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//script[contains(text(),"@type")][1]')
            upcValue = upc.get_attribute("innerText")
            gtin = re.sub('^(.*"gtin13":")',"", upcValue).split('"')[0]

        except:
            gtin = "UPC Not Available"
            pass

        search_it_on_Amazon = "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=" + gtin + "&s=review-rank"
        
        url = driver.current_url

        dateUpdate = datetime.datetime.now()
        dateUpdated = dateUpdate.strftime("%c")

        fields = {
                    
                "stock": stockValue,
                "soldby": soldbyValue,
                "title": titleValue,
                'url': url,
                'date': dateUpdated,
                'upc': gtin,
                'search_it_on_Amazon': search_it_on_Amazon
                    
            }
        list.append(fields)

        print(list)

        cell_list = oos.range('A2:G2')
        
        cell_values = [fields['title'], fields['stock'], fields['soldby'], fields['url'], fields['upc'], fields['search_it_on_Amazon'], fields['date']]


        for i, val in enumerate(cell_values):
            cell_list[i].value = val
            oos.update_cells(cell_list)   
       

    continue
```

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFCvG.png)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Your provided image is the sample input situation? If my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample value of `cell_values` and the sample output values you expect using your sample input situation and your sample value?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, thank you for your attention. The image I inserted demonstrates an example of how I want the table to be built (with data one below the other) and not being updated and rewritten in just one line.

The sample cell_values of each element returns something like:

['Motioneaze Motion Sickness Relief Topical Oil, .08 fl. Oz., 20 application', 'In Stock', 'No seller', 'https://www.walmart.com/ip/Motioneaze-Motion-Sickness-Relief-Topical-Oil-08-fl-Oz-20- application/12346124', '665638000022', 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=665638000022&s=review-rank', 'Tue Sep 27 05:43:53 2022']

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare n number of list before loop, depending on your columns... then append items in your loop... e.g.;

```
stockValue = []

...
while loop
...

try:
    time.sleep(10)
    stock = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="fulfillmentLabel-1P" and contains(., "arrives by")]')))
    stockValue.append("In Stock")
except:
    stockValue.append("Out of Stock")
    pass

# After the loop; using pandas just add those list; like this;
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Stock Value": stockValue})
```

Hope this helps...